# node js add the required models

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, facebook

I am following this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart tutorial to add a web hook.

It's written to use this app https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples

that app is a node js app.

in the app.js, there is this:

```
const 
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  config = require('config'),
  crypto = require('crypto'),
  express = require('express'),
  https = require('https'),  
  request = require('request');
```

when i run the app like this:

> node app.js

i get the following error:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\MyApps\messe
nger-platform-samples-master\node\app.js:14:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

how can I solve it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal (or windows command line), go to messenger-platform-samples/node directory and install messenger-platform-samples by running this command:

```
npm install
```

after that you can run the app:

```
node app.js
```

Comment: and how can I call it please? there is a domain for the server like: "http://www.somethign.com", when i run the app.js, i got a message: `Node app is running on port 5000`

Comment: You can check it locally on your machine by opening http://localhost:5000/ in the browser.

Comment: If you want it to be available via something.com then here is instruction how to deploy node.js application on production server https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

First run `npm install` and this will rectify all errors

Run this command first

```
npm install -g body-parser
```

then create `const bodyParser = require('body-parser')`

Comment: and where is it being called ? I can see this `bodyParser = require('body-parser'),` not `bodyParser()` is it the same ?

Comment: now you update you answer, thanks, where should I run that command? any directory works ?

Comment: windows .... i've run that command, and then run node app.js and still getting the same error